# Div container for bg with no scrollbars

Tags: css, html, background, scrollbar

I've set up my stylesheet to have a container (#container) holding the header/content/sidebars/footer/etc and I've put that in a main wrapper (#mainwrapper).  The effect I'm trying to achieve is similar to College Humor's website; the ads on the side.  I'd like to have a division on the left and right of the container.  What I've done is set it up like this.

```
<div id="mainwrapper">
<div id="leftwall"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="rightwall"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, I want to be able to put an image (or bg image) in the leftwall and rightwall divs, however, I don't want it to trigger the x-scrollbar.  I only want it visible if the viewer's resolution is high enough.  Otherwise, just display #container.

I've set them to float: left, so that they appear on the left and right of the container, but I'm a stuck as to how to make them appear as a background image.

The reason I want to do it this way is that I already have a background image and I want to keep it optimized.  So, instead of having a large image that spans 960+ pixels (#container width), I can have 2 images that are 100px wide.  (the width of #leftwall and #rightwall)

I hope this is understandable and thanks to anyone trying to help in advance!

Have a good day, Brian.

Comment: **I only want it visible if the viewer's resolution is high enough. Otherwise, just display #container.**

I think you'll need to use some JS to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I was figuring.  I'm able to implement and modify javascript fine, but I've never attempted to make a script from scratch.  Know any tutorials that might cover this?  I wouldn't even know what keywords to begin searching for.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want. These days new media queries has been added to make these type of design.

You can define it in your css files for a particular resolution or mobile devices.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1080px){
#leftwall, #rightwall{display:block;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
#leftwall, #rightwall{display:none;}
}</pre>
```

Below is the link where you can learn how to use these queries.
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Hope This Helps,
Cheers,

Comment: I'm currently at work, but as soon as I get home I'll try this out and see if I can get it working properly and be sure to checkmark your answer.  Thanks for the response!  Bc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve; maybe you could show how your css look like so far but have you tried by giving a min-width to the external containers?

Comment: Say, hypothetically, you have a monitor that only spans the width of 960px.  I'd only want the #container div visible with no horizontal scrollbar, however, if you had a monitor that spanned the width of 1080+px, then I'd like the ad containers (#leftwall #rightwall) to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a fiddle with what I think you're trying to achieve, you'll just have to change some numbers to fit your needs: http://www.jsfiddle.net/KrfVR/14/

Adjust the size of the result box to see the side divs appear/disappear.

Comment: I definitely think this is the right track to be on.  What you created in fiddle appears to be working just fine, but I'm having a little trouble implementing it into my code.  I renamed everything and set the dimensions, but I appear to have done something wrong.  The left is called "#leftwall" and is 150px, right is "#rightwall" and is also 150px.  The middle is called "#wrapper" and the container is "#mainwrapper."  The #wrappers width is 960px, and the mainwrapper is 1260px.  Thanks a lot for the help you've already provided.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that my fiddle is using jQuery in case you didn't figure it out. If you haven't added it, that's definitely problem #1. Otherwise just change the #left, #middle, etc and numbers to reflect your site. If you have any other questions please let me know.